# Hiding current activity

Tags: 22.04

For privacy reasons I want to somehow hide my current activity (opened programs or desktop activity, I have trouble explaining this, sorry), without it looking suspicious. Is there a way to do it? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Which activity? Please be more specific. If you mean internet activity in general, using a VPN is the most common option.

Comment: I meant opened programs or desktop activity (I have trouble explaining this, sorry)

Comment: I don't really understand - who's watching? Applications or desktop activity aren't logged unless somebody is watching. If this is a work computer, please follow the guidelines of the company you work at, it's actually their prerogative when you're employed.

Comment: I live in a strict household, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Hmm ok, sorry to hear that. I'm not really sure if this is within the scope of this site. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Artur mentioned, it is difficult to provide answers without knowing more details.

If the observers' technical skill or knowledge of Ubuntu is limited, you may have some success simply swapping between workspaces (ctrl + alt + up or down, and then left/right arrow keys), when needed. You may need to have a decoy software running in the alternative workspace, so it isn't suspiciously blank.

But if someone is more constantly monitoring and/or using screen monitoring software, this wouldn't help at all.

Outside the scope of this site, you may have more luck seeking support with other people who have been in similar situations. There are resources and advice available online on how to leave highly controlled environments, if  that is a goal. But it very much depends on whether or not you are a legal adult yet, and what alternatives are available to you.

Stay safe.

Comment: I haven't thought about second workspace, which can actually work. Thank you so much!